# How can I get a URL for a document on the web that remains stable in the long term?

Tags: webapp-rec

... and by long term, I mean really long term, like at least for a decade, preferably much longer.

What I want to do is to store some text online that I can edit whenever I like. Also, I want to have a URL for this document that I can print out and store somewhere. Then, when the time comes, I want to be sure that when I enter the URL, it still links to the desired document. It doesn't have to be invisible to the public, though that would be a bonus.

Now in theory, this should be easy, because that's exactly what URLs are for, but in reality, web services change their URL structures or vanish completely, so I'm not really sure what to rely on in this case.

My ideas so far:

- just host it myself. Pro: stable as long as I maintain it. Con: I suck at maintaining web services & if I fail to pay my web hoster or the hoster accidently deletes all my data, it's gone.
- use Pastebin. Pro: stable URLs (so far), editable documents. Con: small site, could be shut down at some point.
- use Google Docs. Pro: Google won't go out of business any time soon. Con: Google has a history of shutting down services that everyone thought would stay online forever.

In the end I think it's less about which service solves my problem (because there are tons of them), but which one I can rely on to be stable enough so that it remains operational with an unchanged URL structure. Your thoughts on this?

Comment: There are specialized services, but it can quickly become very expensive. In fact, they are simply online safes (think of online account safes). Very often, there are guarantee periods, an inheritance system if you ever die, increased security, etc.) Not sure this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @pjmg can you name any of these services, or the right search terms I can use? I was unable find anything that matches your description.
And to the others that voted to put this on hold, because it's "too broad". I usually try to give a few examples, but the question itself is pretty simple and on the point: how can I get a URL for something that remains stable for a very long time?

Comment: I think your best bet is to store your documents on every plateform available to date (dropbox, drive, onedrive, etc.. [more here](https://www.techradar.com/news/the-best-cloud-storage)) and hope that one of these will still be around by 2030. If security is an issue, it can become pricey very quickly : I typed something like _how to store data_, _online vault_, _online data vault_. Don't forget to ask support if there's a 10 years guarantee.

Comment: This is a very good question (though not exactly webapp related). As suggested by Ruben, ale, serenesat, please modify it so it gets accepted.